# How to locate and click web element in jubula using java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jubula

I am building a custom jubula framework using java for testing web applications.But I am unable to find java client APIs of Jubula for that. I read that Jubula uses Selenium web driver for identifying/locating web elements like google search box etc. 
But I am unable to find HOW JUBULA USES SELENIUM?
Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Jubula is encapsulating the use of Selenium completely in its own API. This is why you have no specific actions which are similar to Selenium ones. The API is more like a client, that is why there is not much information about the implementation.

The implementation for Jubula actions to Selenium actions is located at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jubula/com.bredexsw.jubula.core/src/). There are two projects which are holding the implementation for Jubula "com.bredexsw.jubula.rc.html.webdriver" and "com.bredexsw.jubula.rc.html.selenium2"

I found also out, that webdriver tests with the Jubula API will not work at the moment since you can not set the location of the webdriver eclip.se/524909.

As for your initial question, at this point you still must use the ITE(UI) from Jubula to generate the ComponentIdentifier see [Exporting the Object Map in the ITE](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help/content/html/developerManual/clientAPI/ch02s03.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information!! Its really helpful!!